# Add discount to shopping-cart using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, shopping-cart, ajaxform

I really need someone who can help me :-)

I want to give customers a discount by clicking various checkboxes in my shop.

Visitors can choose max 4 checkboxes. not 5, 6 etc. Is it possible to do this?

My problem now is that the customer can actually get the item for free - or worse - I have to pay to sell goods to them!

Here is the test-code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox1" class="css-label">banana</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox2" class="css-label">apple</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="css-label">biscuit</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox4" class="css-label">jam </label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox5" class="css-label">orange </label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox6" class="css-label">pinepple </label><br>

<br /><br />

<span id="total"><b>Normal price: </b> 100</span></p>

<script>
var $total = 100;
var $total2 = 100;

$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked)
        $total += -this.value;
    else
        $total -= -this.value;

        if ($total2 > $total)
            $('#total').html('<b>Discount  price: </b>'+$total);
        else
            $('#total').html('<b>Normal price: </b>'+$total);
});
</script>
```

Comment: only one radio button can be chosen at a time, not multiple.

Comment: ok, sorry. meaning checkbox :-)

Comment: `if($('input:checked').length > 4) alert('stop clicking my checkboxes');`

Comment: It works! But I do not want "alerts". Maybe disable remaining check boxes in a way?

Comment: check my answer, buddy!

Comment: Just as I wanted! Thanks so much for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the logic is -

> If the 4 checkboxes are clicked then disable rest

```js
var $total = 100;
var $total2 = 100;

$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
if($('input:checked').length == 4) { 
 $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr("disabled", true);
  }
  else {
   $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr("disabled", false);
  }
    if (this.checked)
        $total += -this.value;
    else
        $total -= -this.value;

        if ($total2 > $total)
            $('#total').html('<b>Discount  price: </b>'+$total);
        else
            $('#total').html('<b>Normal price: </b>'+$total);
            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox1" class="css-label">banana</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox2" class="css-label">apple</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="css-label">biscuit</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox4" class="css-label">jam </label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox5" class="css-label">orange </label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6" class="css-checkbox" value="20" />
<label for="checkbox6" class="css-label">pinepple </label><br>

<span id="total"><b>Normal price: </b> 100</span>
```

Comment: Wow Kalpesh! 

You saved my day!

I thank you with all my heart :-)

Have a great day!

Comment: cool! That was your first question and you got answer very fast :D enjoy your rest of the day: D

Comment: Thanks buddy! Has spent almost 10 hours on this. Slightly embarrassed - and you fixed it in 5 minutes :-)

Comment: Programming is all about logic. 
I cracked your problem in following way - 
1. Maximum 4 checkboxes can be clicked (found how to get number of clicked checkboxes on StackOverflow itself)
2. Disable rest (found how to identify unchecked boxes, got answer again from StackOverflow)

Merged these two and voila, it's working! :)